# Send arraylist of objects results to Activity back from IntentService

Tags: android

I have an IntentService which runs an http request and returns me an ArrayList of Objects.

How am I going to send these data back to the Activity ?

I have searched StackOverflow and googled about it, but most answers have to do with Strings or ints.
It's not a String not an Int just an arrayList of custom objects.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use greenrobot's EventBus or Square's Otto as an event bus. Have the service post an event containing your data. Have the activity subscribe for those events on the bus, then do something with the events.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BroadCast receiver` to send the data from `IntentService` to `Activity`.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction("your_action_here");
   intent.putExtra("key_data", <your_arraylist_here>);
   sendBroadcast(intentUpdate);
```

You need to have this `broadcast receiver` registered in the activity where you want to receive the data.